# Cross-platform commuication test with Hudson

Tags: cross-platform, hudson, jenkins

I need to set up some system communication test with two processes, one running on Linux and one running on Windows.

One way of doing this would be for the test running on Linux to SSH into the Windows host and run the necessary process there. Another option is to trigger two jobs, where one is tied to Linux and the other is tied to Windows.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would have one machine be a controller for the test.  Have that machine be the Hudson server/slave that is triggered to run the test.

While, either OS could take on that role, I've generally found Linux to be the easier platform to automate.  The easiest approach may be to just drive a simple terminal session over a socket.